# Exploring Options for Running Stable Diffusion Without a GPU: Seeking Advice on Hosted Installs or Alternative Solutions

Tags: stable-diffusion

I would like to use Stable Diffusion to generate character designs, train a model on that character, and then generate images.

My laptop does not have a GPU, and I live in a country where it's not possible to easily order high-end computer equipment.  So I can't run it on my desktop device, unfortunately.

Is my best option to rent access to a Stable Diffusion install running on a server? If so, I'd like to run a hosted Stable Diffusion install over a browser, and would happy to pay a monthly rental/hosting fee to do so.

Or are there other options for running Stable Diffusion on someone else's GPU?

Answer (score 0):

One can rent some GPU instance e.g. via AWS and run some stable diffusion codebase e.g. https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/ on it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is my best option to rent access to a Stable Diffusion install running on a server?

There is an alternative way of doing it, which is generating images from websites. Some of them offer a limited trial. For example, [replicate](https://replicate.com/lucataco) and [Clipdrop](https://clipdrop.co/stable-diffusion). With this way, you will not have to pay the rent and spend the time to setup the server.